# Dicionário como argumento de entrada está sendo modificado dentro da função

Tags: python, funções, input, return, dicionário

No código abaixo o dicionário usado como argumento de entrada também está sendo modificado pela função. Preciso realizar uma `deepcopy()` sempre?

```
def muda(a):
    a['valor'] = 50
    return a

dic1 = {'valor': 12}
dic2 = muda(dic1)
print(dic1)
{'valor': 50}
print(dic2)
{'valor': 50}

from copy import deepcopy
dic1 = {'valor': 12}
dic2 = muda(deepcopy(dic1))
print(dic1)
{'valor': 12}
print(dic2)
{'valor': 50}
```

Comment: Dicionário é um tipo mutável, então a passagem dele pelo parâmetro é por referência. Se faz sentido alterar o valor dentro da função, mas não quer que essa alteração seja refletida para fora da função, de fato terá que copiar o objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Se você não quiser modificar o dicionario original será necessário copiar mesmo, pois o dicionário é passado por referencia e não por cópia.
Você também pode usar dict:

```
def muda(a):
    a = dict(a)
    a['valor'] = 50
    return a
```